# why do my @BeforeClass block junit run?

Tags: java, testing, junit, e2e-testing

I try to run junit from my `main()` method:

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
...
logger.debug("className " + className + "methodName " + methodName);

        Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(className), methodName);
        return new JUnitCore().run(request);
}
```

here is my TestClass.

It is called OK when I have no `@BeforeClass` method

but when I add `@BeforeClass` this line passes without getting into the `setup()` method (I try to debug)

```
//    @BeforeClass
//    public void classSetup()
//    {
//        logger = new Logger();
//        stringUtils = new StringUtils(logger);
//    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        logger = new Logger();
        stringUtils = new StringUtils(logger);

    }


    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {..}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method with @BeforeClass annotation should be static.

In your case classSetup method should be static.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void classSetup(){
    logger = new Logger();
    stringUtils = new StringUtils(logger);
}
```

Comment: so `logger` and `stringUtils ` have to be static as well..strange

Comment: yes, logger may not be instance members of test class